# Type mismatch in Swift GCD overlay

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, libdispatch

I'd like to use a [dispatch IO channel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchio) to read some data from a file descriptor. After creating the channel, the next step is to call [`read`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchio/1388941-read), whose declaration is as follows:

```
func read(offset: off_t, 
   length: Int, 
    queue: DispatchQueue, 
ioHandler: @escaping (Bool, DispatchData?, Int32) -> Void)
```

The documentation for the `length` parameter says:

> The number of bytes to read from the channel. Specify SIZE_MAX to continue reading data until an EOF is reached.

Seems easy enough. In my case, I'd like do just that — read until EOF. So I'll pass `SIZE_MAX`:

```
// `queue` and `handler` defined elsewhere
channel.read(offset: 0, length: SIZE_MAX, queue: queue, ioHandler: handler)
```

The astute reader has guessed that the compiler doesn't like this:

> Cannot convert value of type 'UInt' to expected argument type 'Int'

`SIZE_MAX` is of type `UInt`, but `length` is of type `Int`. The compiler offers to fix it:

```
channel.read(offset: 0, length: Int(SIZE_MAX), queue: queue, ioHandler: handler)
```

But of course, at runtime, this doesn't work out so well:

> fatal error: Not enough bits to represent a signed value

Naturally if `SIZE_MAX` is the largest value representable by `UInt`, then `Int` cannot represent it. After some quick searching, I found [this exact issue on the Swift bug tracker](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2107). Since it doesn't seem to yet be addressed — and I'm unsure of my ability to address it myself with a pull request — how can I work around this issue? Or am I missing a way to do what I want?

---

The Swift Stdlib rationales document [covers the explicit decision to import `size_t` as `Int` rather than `UInt`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StdlibRationales.rst#size_t-is-unsigned-but-it-is-imported-as-int). It boils down to "fewer type conversions, and who needs to specify numbers above 2^63 anyways (sorry, 32-bit platforms)." Fair enough, but that doesn't cover issues like mine, where the use of `SIZE_MAX` is part of an API.

Comment: Does passing `length: Int(bitPattern: SIZE_MAX)` work?

Comment: It might! It at least both compiles and does not crash. Honestly, I haven't yet figured out a reasonable way to test this. I can't exactly create a data stream that's 2^64 bytes long, and I don't have a solid handle on how exactly the `Int` gets transformed into a `size_t` over the Swift to C interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Int.max` If you are on a 64 bit platform, you still almost guaranteed to reach end of file before you read `Int.max` bytes. On a 32 bit platform, if your file is very large, you might have to issue more than one read.

Then you should report the issue to Apple. I'm not sure if the Dispatch IO library belongs to Apple or to the Swift Open Source project, or if it is simply a documentation error.

**Update**

The source code is open source, and the read operation is just a simple wrapper to a C function that takes a `size_t` for length.

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-libdispatch/blob/master/src/swift/IO.swift

I haven't tried it, but you can almost certainly use the bit pattern or probably even `-1`. I think I would still go with `Int.max` though.

Comment: I tested passing `Int(bitPattern: SIZE_MAX)` into a dummy C function as `size_t`, and it does actually work as expected, with that argument comparing equal to `SIZE_MAX` in C. I'll accept this on that basis.